# Stripslashes and array_map

Tags: php, function

Should the following code not only remove one backslash rather than two backslashes ? But in the output i see 2 backslashes removed . can somebody explain ?

```
<?php
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

// Example

$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

// Output

print_r($array);
?>
```

The output is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => f'oo
    [1] => b'ar
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => fo'o
            [1] => b'ar
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the string is wrapped with double quotes, there are escape sequences using \ which affect the string as per [this table (PHP manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in the case above \\ means \.

Answer (score 0):

Those two backslashes are actualy **one single character**. read about Escaping Characters.